# System.Data.Linq in netstandard20

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have a netstandard20 project that references a .Net 4.6 Project, all compiles and runs except where I call any functionality in the .Net 4.6 project, I get the following error.

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

In VS 2017, in the project explorer under `Dependancies / SDK / Microsoft.NETCore.App` I can see `System.Data.dll` and `System.Data.Common.dll` but no reference to `System.Data.Linq.dll`, I am assuming this is my problem and it has not been pulled in.

How do I get my project to include `System.Data.Linq.dll`?

If I include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Data.Linq.dll` I get the following error

> BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`System.Data.Linq` is not part of .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0 and therefore cannot be used on that platform.

Even tough you have been able add a reference to a .NET 4.6 project via the compatibility shims, it fails at runtime because of a feature that is not available on the target runtime

Answer (score 29):

I was able to solve my need to use `System.Data.Linq` in a .NET Standard 2.0 library by using the [Mindbox.Data.Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mindbox.Data.Linq/2.0.7) NuGet package.

After installing it you should be able to use the `System.Data.Linq` namespace just like you could when writing for .NET Framework!

Comment: Thanks you, this project probably saved me weeks of work! Still need to move off Linq-to-SQL one day but at least it doesn't block the migration to Core anymore :).

Comment: If this works you will have saved the day, week and maybe the month.  I still think LinqToSql was the superior ORM for those who like to get things done and know how they are doing them. I guess I'll join the lemmings and leap into the sea.

Comment: On 2018-05-29, Microsoft published `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` which "Provides extensions to form LINQ expressions and method queries against DataTable objects."

Comment: You can find the source of the `Mindbox.Data.Linq` package here https://github.com/mindbox-cloud/data-linq